# Why is the sum of two mutable maps in kotlin a map

Tags: kotlin, mutablemap

I have two functions that return mutable maps

```
fun mumapone() = mutableMapOf<String, Any>("one" to 1)
fun mumaptwo() = mutableMapOf<String, Any>("two" to 1) + mumapone()
```

the type of fun `mumaptwo()` becomes a `Map` and not a `MutableMap`, why? It seems that the sum of two mutable maps will always be a `Map`, why is that?

I can also use variables but the output will be the same

```
    fun fakeConfig() = xx +  yy
    val xx = mutableMapOf<String, Any>("one", 1)
    val yy = mutableMapOf<String, Any>("two", 1)
```

the type of `fakeConfig()` will still be Map, the only way to change this is to cast it or

```
    (xx +  yy).toMutatleMap()
```

so to repeat the question why is the sum of two mutable maps becomes a map and not a mutable map.

cheers,

es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sum the two maps the interface that is assumed by default is Map, since MutableMap is an implementation of the interface it cannot be assumed for the `+` operator.

However if you want to avoid casting or conversion you can simply create a third mutable map and sum the two other maps in it. That map will keep the type and will not need casting.

More information in the kotlin docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/map-operations.html#map-write-operations

Answer (score 4):

In general `+` is for immutable operatons that return you a new data-structure.

You could implement the `+` operator for MutableMap, but that wouldn't be a good idea because the [`putAll()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/put-all.html) function already exists for that:

```
fun main() {
    val foo = mutableMapOf(1 to "one", 2 to "two")
    val bar = mapOf(3 to "three", 4 to "four")
    foo.putAll(bar)
    println(foo)
}
```

Output:

```
{1=one, 2=two, 3=three, 4=four}
```

It's best to use `+` to get a new immutable map, or explicitly use mutable operations such as `putAll()`.

You could write `mumaptwo` like this:

```
fun mumaptwo() = mumapone().putAll(mutableMapOf<String, Any>("two" to 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

**plus**

Creates a new read-only map by replacing or adding entries to this map from another map.

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.plus(
    map: Map<out K, V>
): Map<K, V>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Mutable maps offer map-specific write operations. These operations let you change the map content using key-based access to the values.*

**The `MutableMap` is nothing but a map having write operation**

There are certain rules that define write operations on maps:

> Values can be updated. In turn, keys never change: once you add an entry, its key is constant.

> For each key, there is always a single value associated with it. You can add and remove whole entries.

**ADD Operation**

> To add a new key-value pair to a mutable map, use `put()`.

> To add multiple entries at a time, use `putAll()`

You can also add new entries to maps using the shorthand operator form. There are two ways:

> plusAssign `(+=)` operator.

> the `[]` operator alias for `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

The plus operation is only defined in Map interface and its result is an immutable map.

The MutableMap implementation doesn't override this operation so, when you call it using mutable maps you are actually calling a Map operation instead of MutableMap operation.
As you can see here

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/